# Buttons won't hide after returning from another View Controller

Tags: uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, hidden

I have an app with a tab bar and a number of tab bar items, each with its own VC. On the HOME tab bar view I have a set of `UIButtons` programmatically generated. I have one specific button ("Hide Buttons") that, when pressed, disables/hides the others. Works as expected.

However, when I tap a second tab bar item and then return to the original and tap the "Hide Buttons" button - they stay visible/enabled. If I set a breakpoint in the method called by the "Hide Buttons" button, I noted the memory address of one of the buttons and after tabbing to another view and returning, I notice the same UIButton memory address is different. Not sure why.

The `UIButtons` are all defined in the HOME VC inside the `@implementation` block in the form `UIButton *originalButton; UIButton *hideButtonsButton;` etc and initialized in viewDidAppear: using the following type of code:

```
// ORIGINAL BUTTON TAG = 1
originalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[originalButton addTarget:self action:@selector(originalButtonWasPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
originalButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 30.0, 100.0, 39.0);
UIImage *originalButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"originalreg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
UIImage *originalButtonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"originalregblue.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
[originalButton setBackgroundImage:originalButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[originalButton setBackgroundImage:originalButtonImageHighlight forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.view addSubview:originalButton];
```

Any guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Duh. I moved the call to the button initialization method to viewDidLoad vs. viewDidAppear. All is fine now.